# How to solve issue of page redirecting jquery?

Tags: jquery

When error occurs my page gets redirect on another page without displaying error message.

Is there any way to write `e.preventDefault()`; inside ajax error `function()`? or any other way to stop page from getting redirect on another page when error occurs?

I can not able to declare `e.preventDefault()`; globally as on success i am doing render of page on another page from controller.

This is my ajax code :

```
$('#request').on("submit", function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find("div.error").hide();
    var _data = $(e.currentTarget).serialize();
    var obj = $("#track_request").val();
    if(obj == ""){
        $("#track").text("Enter Request Number.");
        $("#track").fadeIn(1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#track").fadeOut(1000);
        }, 2000);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST" ,
          url: "/track",
          data: _data,
          success: function(data) {
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, event) {
                if(obj != "" && xhr.status == 500){
                    $("#track").text("Enter Valid Request Number.");
                    $("#track").fadeIn(1000);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                       $("#track").fadeOut(1000);
                    }, 3000);
                }
          },
    });
```

});

Comment: If you're using AJAX for the submit, why not have the `e.preventDefault();` as the very first line of that function?

Comment: I don't get it. You don't have a `e.preventDefault();` at all. So when you trigger the submit (e.g. via click on the submitbutton) it will redirect you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `e.preventDefault()` as first line and then submit the form when ajax is successful on `success` function.

Something like this:

```
$('#request').on("submit", function(e) {
// Added 
e.preventDefault();

$(e.currentTarget).find("div.error").hide();
var _data = $(e.currentTarget).serialize();
var obj = $("#track_request").val();
if(obj == ""){
    $("#track").text("Enter Request Number.");
    $("#track").fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#track").fadeOut(1000);
    }, 2000);
    // Not needed
    //e.preventDefault();
}
$.ajax({
      type: "POST" ,
      url: "/track",
      data: _data,
      success: function(data) {
          // Added
          $('#form_id').submit();
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, event) {
            if(obj != "" && xhr.status == 500){
                $("#track").text("Enter Valid Request Number.");
                $("#track").fadeIn(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                   $("#track").fadeOut(1000);
                }, 3000);
            }
      },
});
```

});

Edit: You might also want to add the ajax call into `else` so that it doesn't get executed when the first field check fails.

Comment: i am doing return ok(views.html.request.render("Request", p)); from my controller so after adding e.prevetDefault(); globally, this return function is not getting fire.